# UIView animation slide similar to this picture

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiview

I have been searching for a way to do the following:

http://a5.mzstatic.com/us/r1000/014/Purple/9c/af/dc/mzl.hdgiidhq.320x480-75.jpg

I want to have a view but be able to slide through them so they show up one by one..
each view pulls up new data from my plist.

I am not sure what this method is called to properly research it.

could someone please point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out the [sample code for Page Control](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/PageControl/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40007795). It shows the basics of a paging scroll view with different subviews on each page.

One of the important concepts is reusing the subviews, which you'll find out about in the sample code.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need a scroll view with paging. User can view its subviews by swiping.
 This is not an innovative functionality. It is the default functionality of scrollview.

Hope this helps ...